# Grid ColumnDefinition.Width in DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, grid, controltemplate

In my project, I've made a control that inherits from `Control`. It is called `DialogHeader` and, as its name stands, is for displaying a header on modal, non-resizable dialogs. In truth, it binds by default to its parent `Window`. The control has a property called `IconLocation`, i.e. whether the image should be displayed on the left or right side of the control's label:

```
[Image] [Label] -- or -- [Label] [Image]
```

The template used with `DialogHeader` is basically the following:

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition x:Name="COLN_Left" Width="auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
      <ColumnDefinition x:Name="COLN_Right" Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Grid.Column="0" Name="PART_Image" />
    <Separator Grid.Column="1"
               Visibility="Collapsed" Width="{TemplateBinding SpacerWidth}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Name="PART_Text" />
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplare.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="ImageLocation" Value="Right">
      <Setter TargetName="PART_Image" Property="Grid.Column" Value="2" />
      <Setter TargetName="PART_Text"  Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" />
      <!-- The following doesn't work! Help! -->
      <Setter TargetName="COLN_Left"  Property="Width"       Value="*" />
      <Setter TargetName="COLN_Right" Property="Width"       Value="auto" />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Simply put, when the `ImageLocation` property is set to `Location.Right`, the widths of `COLN_Left` and `COLN_Right` should be exchanged. So instead of `[auto][auto][*]`, I should have `[*][auto][auto]`.

How can I make this work from the `ControlTemplate`? If not, is there are way that doesn't involve using C# code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part does work, it possibly is just not what you want i presume. Try to remove it and the result should be different.

Comment: It doesn't work in my project—at least the way I want it. I may have to look whether another template or style overrides.

Comment: Template-internal things are not easily overridden though.

Comment: Certainly not; however, it is so that I actually re-templated the Control in the UI project and *forgot* to add `Width="auto"` on the unnamed column (the one with the spacer).